# Finding RTF code associated with selected text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, vb.net, richtextbox, rtf

I am using winform RichTextBox and I wonder if we can find the corresponding rtf code (or at least whereabouts of it) when selecting text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [SelectedRtf property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectedrtf.aspx).